# Pointwise convergence resisting averaging

Tags: functional-analysis

Can you give an example of a sequence of continuous functions $f_n:[0,1]\to [0,1]$, such that $f_n\to 0$ pointwise and there is no subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ for which $\frac 1 m\sum_{k=1}^{m}f_{n_k}$ tends to zero uniformly?

I think it's the same as asking whether the Banach space of continuous real valued functions has the "weak Banach-Saks property", but I was unable to find out the answer.

Comment: @JesseMadnick: not much. I was hoping someone would just know the answer...

Comment: Did you try some triangular wave which increases frequency but such that $f_{n + 1}$ has the same peaks as $f_n$ but more of them?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?] *not much. I was hoping someone would just know the answer...*

Comment: It was somewhat rhetoric, @Didier. (if you are replying on my comment)

Comment: @Jonas: Your comment is standard.

Answer (score 2):

That $C[0,1]$ fails the weak Banach Saks property appears as problem 17 in chapter VII in Joseph Diestel's *Sequences and Series in Banach Spaces*.

The problem gives an outline:

1) For $k$ a fixed positive integer, construct a nonnegative sequence $(g_n^k)_n$ in $B(C[0,1])$ satisfying:

- $g_n^k(t)=0$ if $t\notin ((k-1)/k, k/(k+1))$.
- $(g_n^k)$ converges pointwise to 0 on $[0,1]$.
- If $n_1<n_2<\cdots<n_k$, then there is an $a\in[0,1]$ with $g_{n_1}^k(a)=g_{n_2}^k(a)=\cdots=g_{n_k}^k(a)=1$.

2) Define $f_n=g_n^1+g_n^2+\cdots+g_n^n$. Show that:

- $(f_n)$ is weakly null in $C[0,1]$ (which is equivalent to saying $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to 0 and is bounded).
- If $n_1<n_2<\cdots<n_m<n_{m+1}<\cdots< n_{2m}$, then $(f_{n_1}+\cdots f_{n_{2m}})(t)\ge {1\over 2}$ for all $t\in[0,1]$ 
  (I believe Diestel has a typo here, it should be $\ge m/2$ for *some* $t\in[0,1]$).

This was first proved by J. Schreier in *Ein Gegenbeispiel zur Theorie der schwachen Konvergence*, Studia Math. 2 (1930), 58–62.
 H. P. Rosenthal's article in volume 2 of  *Handbook of the Geometry of Banach Spaces* (proposition 4.21, page 1585) may also be helpful.

Comment: The question did say $f_n : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ so they are bounded in $C[0,1]$.  (I missed this at first also.)

Comment: @Nate Ah! I should have seen that...

Comment: How is $(\frac12, n)$ in $[0, 1]$ for $n \geqslant 1$?

Comment: @Jonas I initially misread the question, and thought the OP wanted only pointwise convergence.